# Showing that $\sqrt{1+z^2} - zx$ = $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $z = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently trying to understand a paper where a Fourier transform was calculated by the principle of stationary phase.
When I do the steps I end up with an expression very close to that of the author, but the author manages to further simplify the solution.

In order for my solution to match that of the author I would need to show that

$\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ = $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

I haven't managed to manipulate the RHS to be equal to the LHS and WolframAlpha hasn't been helping either.

I've been stuck on this particular formula for a couple of days so I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: $1 + \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$ would be a good start ...

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt {1-x^{2}}$ makes this really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I'll file this under 'missing the forest for the trees'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain it's $1-x^2>0$ and we obtain: $$\sqrt{1+z^2}-zx=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not so difficult.

Reduce to the common denominator under the square root and the numerator is $1$. Then summing the two terms, you get the ratio of $1-x^2$ and its square root.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $\arcsin x=t\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le \dfrac\pi2$

and $ x=\sin t,\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos t$

$$\sqrt{1+z^2}=z\sin t+\cos t$$

$$\iff\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\cos t+\dfrac z{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\sin t=1$$

Set $\arctan z=u,z=\tan u\implies\dfrac z{\sin u}=\dfrac1{\cos u}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1^2+z^2}{\sin^2u+\cos^2u}}$

Considering the '+' sign,
$$\cos\left(t-u\right)=1$$

$$\implies t-u=2n\pi$$

$$z=\tan u=\tan t=?$$